# How to have proper exception for Firebase quota limit in Firebase PHP wrapper?

Tags: javascript, php, firebase

I'm building a feature in my site as a demonstration of realtime data using firebase. I want my Firebase code in php to have capability of figuring out associated firebase account's free tier has just hit API call quota limit without crashing the site. Let's say you are pushing, setting, reading, deleting data using PHP firebase wrapper, how would you correctly throw / catch exception for quota limit? I want to figure this out in both PHP and Javascript.

Comment: https://github.com/ktamas77/firebase-php

Comment: That's what I'm using as a library